# convert group by query to linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert below query in linq

```
 select ta.id, ta.name, min(tb.id) from tableA ta
 left join tableB tb on tb.fkid=ta.id
 group by ta.id, ta.name
```

I tried below

```
 var query = (from tableA in tableARepository.AsQueryable()
            join tableB in tableBRepository.AsQueryable() on
                tableA.Id equals tableB.fkid

                     group grp by new {tableA.Id, tableA.Name } into groupedCol
                     select new
                     {
                         Id = groupedCol.Key.Id,
                         Name = groupedCol.Key.Name,
                         fkId = grouppedCol.Min // cant get column fkid from tableB

                     }

            );
```

I am not able to get Min of column `fkid` of `tableB`

What is missing here or how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the results that you are looking for without using `Join` or `GroupBy`:

```
var restrictTo = new[] {1, 2};
var query = tableARepository.AsQueryable()
    // I want to add where clause like tableA.Id in (1,2)
    .Where(a => restrictTo.Contains(a.Id))
    .Select(a => new {
        Id = a.Id
    ,   Name = a.Name
    ,   FkId = tableBRepository.AsQueryable().Min(b => b.fkid=a.id)
    });
```

Comment: i want to add where clause like tableA.Id in (1,2).. how can i add it

Comment: I get exceptions because my Id column is integer,  so i tried doing this a => restrictTo.Contains(a.Id.ToString())

Comment: @Happy `restrictTo` consists of `int`s, too, so `ToString` is not necessary. What kind of exception do you get?

Comment: i get this ":"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.","

Comment: @Happy Please remove `ToString()`, it's not supposed to be there. If `a.Id` is an `int`, and you followed what's in the answer, you should get no error, because `restrictTo` is an array of integers, not an array of strings.

Comment: Actually i get array and then i split it and add comma

Comment: @Happy Could you please try what I suggested without changes, and see if it works? Please ask another question about array manipulations and inserting commas. What you're doing sounds rather suspicious, so you would need a code example to make it clear. In particular, I see no reason to split an array or to insert any commas into it.

Comment: Ok i will ask new question

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`GroupJoin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx)

```
from tableA in tableARepository.AsQueryable()
join tableB in tableBRepository.AsQueryable() on
tableA.Id equals tableB.fkid into tb
select new 
       {
           Id = tableA.Id,
           Name = tableA.Name,
           fkId = tb.Min(x => x.id)
       }
```

Comment: so you mean there will be no group by clause in linq?

Comment: Does this perform the left join?

Comment: no it's different. from the documentation: GroupJoin: _It pairs each element from the first collection with a set of correlated elements from the second collection._